How to Get Total Memory Usage of a Chrome Tab
I am trying to obtain the total memory usage (similar to what is shown in Chrome's Task Manager as "Memory Footprint") of a Chrome tab. While I can get the JavaScript heap size using performance.memory, I need a more comprehensive measure that includes the total memory usage of the tab.
Memory Footprint example
Here is the code I am using:
(async function getMemoryFootprint() {
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/');
    
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    await client.send("HeapProfiler.enable");
    await client.send("HeapProfiler.collectGarbage");
    await client.send("HeapProfiler.collectGarbage");
    await client.send("HeapProfiler.disable");

    const memoryMetrics = await page.metrics();
    await browser.close();

    console.log(`Total JS Heap Size: ${memoryMetrics.JSHeapTotalSize} bytes`);
    console.log(`Used JS Heap Size: ${memoryMetrics.JSHeapUsedSize} bytes`);
})();


Issues: The script retrieves JavaScript heap size metrics, but this is not enough to get the total memory footprint of the tab.

I guess the only way is to write a chrome extension and use it in puppeteer. The extension would call chrome.processes API and somehow expose the result e.g. by adding it to DOM of the page.

Can you use Performance Web API?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

@alexandr.mirzoyan hi, performance.memory return jsHeap* size. I want to get the total size of the browser tab.

This code snippet demonstrates how to use Puppeteer to gather memory usage information for each process associated with a Chromium browser instance:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import { exec } from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
const client = await browser.target().createCDPSession();
const { processInfo } = await client.send("SystemInfo.getProcessInfo");
client.detach();

for (const process of processInfo) {
    const { stdout } = await promisify(exec)(`ps -o rss= -p ${process.id}`);
    process.memoryKb = stdout.trim();
}

await browser.close();

console.log("Process info:", processInfo);

result:
Process info: [
  { type: 'browser', id: 11159, cpuTime: 0.13, memoryKb: '141900' },
  { type: 'renderer', id: 11229, cpuTime: 0, memoryKb: '54196' },
  { type: 'renderer', id: 11230, cpuTime: 0.01, memoryKb: '79408' },
  { type: 'GPU', id: 11190, cpuTime: 0.03, memoryKb: '95092' },
  { type: 'storage.mojom.StorageService', id: 11193, cpuTime: 0, memoryKb: '40860' }
]

